# taberror: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation when using vendor "logentries" package

Tags: python, logging, pycharm, python-3.5, logentries

I have installed a vendor packages called "logentries" but i get the below error:

> TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
>
> .../lib/python3.5/site-packages/logentries/metrics.py", line 58

I am using PyCharm IDE and all settings are correct:

```
Tab Size: 4
Indent: 4
Continuation Indent: 8
```

As a workaround i had to reformat the file "metrics.py" that have this issue manually in IDE, but this workaround will not work if i deploy the code to unix environment unless i use formatter packages to manually format the file "metrics.py".

I am using Python 3.5 and the vendor package supports Python 2 and 3 ,please see package details:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Logentries

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What version of logentries are you using? Their dev team already fixed the problem, so just upgrade the module with pip.